# Is there a way to replace cells of a particular value with multiple cells?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I need to replace any cell that has a value of "outgoing" with multiple cells such as (0), (1), (0), (0), (2), in Excel. Is there a way to actually make this happen? I am doing this for a research project. Every item in my data needs to be coded on five different scales. There are 30-or-so items make up for almost half of the data. It would be enormously helpful to be able to simply replace the high frequency items with the five values at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand the result you are looking for but here goes:

How about using the **Find and Replace** functionality to replace all instances of "outgoing" with "(0),(1),(0),(0),(2)" and then use the **Text to Columns** functionality to split the single column with "(0),(1),(0),(0),(2)" in to five separate columns, thus each value would be in its own cell.

You would need to split based on a delimiter (probably ",") and you should do all your replacing before you start splitting.  Obviously you should test on some sample data first - Find and Replace is not your friend if you are not certain about your data set.

Comment: Yes! I think that would work!! I never thought of simply using text to columns to make this happen. Thanks!

Comment: Great.  Don't forget to select an answer as accepted once you have confirmed the best response.